# jQuery matching table with array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here is part of my table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>jack</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>450</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>james</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>450</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>john</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>450</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My jQuery code looks like this

```
var toShow = [
  "jack",
  "john"
];

var addClass = [
  "jack"
];


$('tr:contains(toShow)').remove();
$('tr:contains(addClass)').addClass("done");
```

The goal is compare toShow array with my table. If string doesn't not exist, remove tr element with it. If my table matches item from addClass than add class.

Im not sure why my code do not works. Result shoud be remove last tr element from table and for first add class .done

Comment: $('tr:contains(xxxx)') does not pass the var to the contains you need to use quotes and likely loop too. JS does not work by wishful thinking. See the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/filter/ might help you

Comment: I wonder why run `remove` to values inside `toShow` array...

Comment: You likely want to change to `var addClass = [
  "james"
];` if you want to see anything with a "done" class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
var toShow = [
  "jack",
  "john"
];

var addClass = [
  "jack"
];

toShow.forEach( function(item){
  $('tr:contains(' + item + ')').remove();
});

addClass.forEach( function(item){
   $('tr:contains(' + item + ')').addClass("done");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>jack</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>450</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>james</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>450</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>john</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>450</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Since the addClass array item has been deleted from the DOM already, you don't see any class being added.

Comment: @mplungjan it doesn't add since `jack` element has already been deleted based on `toShow` array

Comment: @mplungjan If i change the item to `james`, then it works.

Comment: yes, I could not imagine removing stuff later to have a class added

Answer (score 1):

> Im not sure why my code do not works.

Because you're literally asking it to find the text `toShow`, you're not using a value from your `toShow` object.

To do that, if you want to use `:contains`, use string concatenation; to do all values, you'll need to use a multiple selector.

```
$('tr:contains(' + toShow.join('), tr:contains(') + ')').remove();
```

...which creates this selector string with your example:

```
$('tr:contains(jack), tr:contains(john)').remove();
```

Or of course, loop through the array and handle each entry individually, again with string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks, but it makes oposite what I want. I wanted to show only contains of toShow array.

Comment: @Ostrov: It's hard to read `$('tr:contains(toShow)').remove();` as meaning anything other than "remove the elements that contain what's in `toShow`". But just adjust the logic however you want, the fundamental thing is doing the string concatenation.